# Check and extract composition args in sympy python

Tags: python, sympy

i want to check if an expression is a composition of two functions and extract the args for example

```
Log(x-1) :
```

i want get :

```
[log(x),x-1]
```

and

```
sin(x)/(1-sin(x))
```

i want get :

```
[x/(1-x),sin(x)]
```

are there any sympy function or should i do it by myself

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple function that does it. You could use `cse` to pull out common subexpressions and `expr.args` to pull out non-common subexpressions from those.

Comment: but cse doesent extract  the subexpressions of usuale function such as ln(x+1) [[x+1,x0],ln(x0)]

Comment: You'll need to use `expr.args` for the subexpressions that don't appear multiple times. There's also some work that is needed beyond this to put it in the form you want (this isn't a complete answer).